# Using buttons to "simulate" mouse-up, mouse-move, and mouse-down events

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Hello**

I'm currently working on a project that is very similar to the following codepen that I found a long while ago. It's essential a Tinder-like application;

https://codepen.io/suez/pen/MaeVBy

Within the codepen is the following JavaScript/jQuery:

```
function pullChange() {
    animating = true;
    deg = pullDeltaX / 10;
    $card.css("transform", "translateX("+ pullDeltaX +"px) rotate("+ deg +"deg)");

    var opacity = pullDeltaX / 100;
    var rejectOpacity = (opacity >= 0) ? 0 : Math.abs(opacity);
    var likeOpacity = (opacity <= 0) ? 0 : opacity;
    $cardReject.css("opacity", rejectOpacity);
    $cardLike.css("opacity", likeOpacity);
};

$(document).on("mousedown touchstart", ".demo__card:not(.inactive)", function(e) {
      if (animating) return;

      $card = $(this);
      $cardReject = $(".demo__card__choice.m--reject", $card);
      $cardLike = $(".demo__card__choice.m--like", $card);
      var startX = e.pageX || e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;

      $(document).on("mousemove touchmove", function(e) {
        var x = e.pageX || e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
        pullDeltaX = (x - startX);
        if (!pullDeltaX) return;
        pullChange();
      });

      $(document).on("mouseup touchend", function() {
        $(document).off("mousemove touchmove mouseup touchend");
        if (!pullDeltaX) return; // prevents from rapid click events
        release();
      });
});
```

What I'm looking to achieve is the implementation of two buttons to *"simulate"* the mouse dragging. So - if you play with the codepen - you'll see that it's possible to drag the cards left and right. A "like" or "dislike" decision is then made based upon how far left or right it was dragged. Also, if you drag a card too far or too little in one direction, the card will snap to a set point upon release.

I want to give the users an option to click a "Like" or 'Dislike" button instead of dragging. Hitting one of these buttons will then perform the same actions as if the card had been dragged.

Is this simple to do? Can anybody give me any guidance? I've spent a bit of time with this, and can't seem to get it to work, so any help would be ***greatly*** appreciated!

Let me know if you need more data or information.

**Thanks!**

Comment: can't you `trigger(eventName)`?

Comment: No, don't think so? The "pullDeltaX" variable is set depending on the position of the mouse along the x axis (left to right). The button click won't be able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your question left out the important parts of the code; the `pullChange()` and `release()` functions. Since those are the functions that actually control the card moving, you should be able to bind them to a button click with a slight caveat. `pullChange()` utilizes the DeltaX variable and expects it to be there to tell it how far to move, so you'll need to set this by hand since there won't be a drag event telling it how far.

Comment: Sorry, the remaining code is within the codepen - I figured it would be a waste to just copy and paste the entire contents here when a working copy can be found there. So, you're saying that upon button click, I'll need to manually set the "pullDeltaX" variable?

Comment: That's fine, that's how I found it ;) But those two functions are more important than the part you posted.

**EDIT: (Hit enter too quickly)** You'll need to set `DeltaX` and call the correct functions in the correct order. It may even involve a timeout and calling `pullChange()` multiple times depending on exactly what you're going for.

Comment: Hm, OK - that makes sense. The other issue would that "$card" is defined as "$(this)" on the mousedown event. In terms of a button click, I'll need "$card" to be set to the foremost card on display?